# Why would CURL time out in 1000ms when I have set up timeout upto 3000ms?

Tags: php, curl

In one of my script I have set up curl time out, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT_MS, to 3000ms, but curl time outs much before than that, at an average of 1000ms. Why would it time out so early?

Comment: Are you sure it's the actual connection that's timing out, rather than the operation (i.e. CURLOPT_TIMEOUT_MS, rather than  CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT_MS?)

Comment: matt, I log all failed CURL calls, here is a log entry `Curl error: Operation timed out after 1000 milliseconds with 0 bytes received`, and here is code `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT_MS, 3000); curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 3 ); `, even if `CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT_MS` isn't respected `CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT` should be respected.

Comment: Yes, but what I was asking was CURLOPT_TIMEOUT/CURLOPT_TIMEOUT_MS, rather than CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT/CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT_MS. That is, the actual *operation* timeout, rather than just the connection timeout. One pair controls the *connection* timeout, which is what you're setting, and the other pair controls the *operation* timeout, i.e. the timeout for actually getting the data after you're connected.

Comment: crap!!! so what you are saying means that connect time out should be less then simple time out and I think I have got the issue here,post your comment as an answer :(

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I believe the timeout you are seeing is a CURL operation timeout, rather than a connection timeout. These two are different.

`CURLOPT_TIMEOUT` (and `CURLOPT_TIMEOUT_MS` for millisecond values) control the timeout for the work CURL does after it's connected. `CUROPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT` (and `CUROPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT_MS`) control the timeout for the initial connection (DNS lookup, establishing the connection, etc.)

If I'm right, then if you set CURLOPT_TIMEOUT higher than 1, you should find that your timeout doesn't trip at 1000ms any more.

Comment: Matt Gibson, you saved the day :)

Answer (score 0):

Check the version of your CURL and PHP installation. CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT_MS added in cURL 7.16.2. Available since PHP 5.2.3. http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php