# PHP stalls on loop of curl function with bad url

Tags: php, curl, timeout

I have a database of a few thousand URL's that I am checking for links on pages (end up looking for specific links) and so I am throwing the below function through a loop and every once and awhile one of the URL's is bad and then the entire program just stalls and stops running and starts building up memory used. I thought adding the CURLOPT_TIMEOUT would fix this but it didn't. Any ideas?

```
$options = array(
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,         // return web page
    CURLOPT_HEADER         => false,        // don't return headers
    CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,         // follow redirects
    CURLOPT_ENCODING       => "",           // handle all encodings
    CURLOPT_USERAGENT      =>  "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.8.1.13) Gecko/20080311 Firefox/2.0.0.13'",     // who am i
    CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER    => true,         // set referer on redirect
    CURLOPT_TIMEOUT        => 2,          // timeout on response
    CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS      => 10,           // stop after 10 redirects
    CURLOPT_POST            => 0,            // i am sending post data
       CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS     => $curl_data,    // this are my post vars
    CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST => 0,            // don't verify ssl
    CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => false,        //
    CURLOPT_VERBOSE        => 1                //
);

$ch      = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt_array($ch,$options);
$content = curl_exec($ch);
$err     = curl_errno($ch);
$errmsg  = curl_error($ch) ;
$header  = curl_getinfo($ch);
curl_close($ch);

//  $header['errno']   = $err;
//  $header['errmsg']  = $errmsg;
$header['content'] = $content;

#Extract the raw URl from the current one
$scheme = parse_url($url, PHP_URL_SCHEME); //Ex: http
$host = parse_url($url, PHP_URL_HOST); //Ex: www.google.com
$raw_url = $scheme . '://' . $host; //Ex: http://www.google.com

#Replace the relative link by an absolute one
$relative = array();
$absolute = array();

#String to search
$relative[0] = '/src="\//';
$relative[1] = '/href="\//';

#String to remplace by
$absolute[0] = 'src="' . $raw_url . '/';
$absolute[1] = 'href="' . $raw_url . '/';

$source = preg_replace($relative, $absolute, $content); //Ex: src="/image/google.png" to src="http://www.google.com/image/google.png"

return $source;
```

Comment: Are you throwing ^everything in that function in a loop?

Comment: this function is not defined in the loop, it's this function then my for loop after that calls this function each iteration.

Comment: Have you located the exact line of code where your script stalls? I'm just curious, because how can you tell it's that function in concrete? If it is, which of the many lines?

Comment: @hakre I assume it is from this function considering the rest of the code is mysql connect and a for loop that calls a url, puts it into that function, then prints the source.

afuzzyllama can't believe I missed that, thanks. Still stalls though.

Answer (score 1):

curl_exec will return false if it cannot find the URL.
 The HTTP status code will be zero. 
Check the results of curl_exec and check the HTTP status
code too.

```
$content = curl_exec($ch);
$httpStatus = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
if ( $content === false) {
   if ($httpStatus == 0) {
    $content = "link was not found";
   }
}
....
```

The way you have it currently, the line of code

```
header['content'] = $content;
```

will get the value of false.  This is not what you 
want.

I am using curl_exec and my code does not stall if
it cannot find the url. The code keeps running. 
You may end up with nothing in your browser though
and a message in the Firebug Console like "500 Internal Server Error".
Maybe that's what you mean by stall.

Answer (score 0):

So basically you don't know and just guess that the curl request is stalling.

For this answer I can only guess as well then. You might need to set one of the following curl option as well: `CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT`

If the connect already stalls, the other timeout setting might not be taken into account. I'm not entirely sure, but please see [Why would CURL time out in 1000ms when I have set up timeout upto 3000ms?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6211282/why-would-curl-time-out-in-1000ms-when-i-have-set-up-timeout-upto-3000ms).