# How to fix "Operation timed out after 1000 milliseconds with 0 bytes received" error?

Tags: c++, libcurl

For our integration project, we make rest calls using libcurl library functions. However, we are facing some intermittent issue while making a rest call.The issue is that the `curl_easy_perform()` method is returning an error code with following description:

> Operation timed out after 1000 milliseconds with 0 bytes received

Can someone please help me on this ?

Comment: Maybe increase the timeout. One second isn't that long if the server is busy. Other than that, there's not much for us to go on here.

Comment: none of the default timeouts seem to be 1000 ms, I wonder if curl_easy_reset would help you

Comment: according to this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6211282/why-would-curl-time-out-in-1000ms-when-i-have-set-up-timeout-upto-3000ms and the message you are seeing an "operation timeout" governed by the values `CURLOPT_TIMEOUT`/`CURLOPT_TIMEOUT_MS`

Comment: I am still not able to get on how to resolve this issue :(